How to create a MATLAB "library of objects"
I'm currently working on a MATLAB project where I need to create a lot of 'object libraries'.
For example, I am setting up a unit and quantity system where a unit is stored as a 'Unit' object.
I would like to enumerate all the default units that are in use so that they can be easily accessed.
However, I would also like users to be able to define their own units on-the-go. If I make this object an enumeration, I can't define additional units.
I tried setting up a second class called 'UnitEnumeration' which inherited from 'Unit' and was an enumeration of default units. This worked at first, until I discovered that default units are created with class 'UnitEnumeration', while user-defined units have class 'Unit'. This means they can't be added or multiplied, which I need them to be able to do. This was also likely to cause other problems down the line.
I've finally had the idea of setting up a class called 'UnitLibrary', which inherits features from an abstract 'Library' superclass (as I will be needing to use this sort of thing a lot so it would be nice if I could abstract most of the code I need). This 'UnitLibrary' has units saved as constant properties, with values initialised as 'Unit' objects. For example:
classdef UnitLibrary
    properties (Constant)
        Metre = Unit(quantity = Quantity.Length)
        Inch = Unit(quantity = Quantity.Length, conversionFactor = 0.0254)
        ...
    end
end

This is by far the best solution I've found so far, but there are still a few drawbacks.
I'm setting up some methods to make it easy to use this library, ideally abstracting them to the 'Library' superclass to make my life much easier later on.
For example, I'd like to be able to access a library member using a string input. I wrote a 'fromString' method:
classdef (Abstract) Library
    methods (Static)
        function member = fromString(library, memberName)
            % (some error handling and parsing)
            member = library.(memberName)
        end
        ... % Other similar methods
    end
end

I'd like these methods to be static so that I don't have to load a 'UnitLibrary' object every time I want to use them. However, I need access to the 'library' object in the method, so I pass it in manually. Thus, calling this method looks like this:
metre = UnitLibrary.fromString(UnitLibrary(), "metre")

This is a pretty minor annoyance, but it's got me thinking there must be some way around this.
I have tried a few different ways of structuring this code before I arrived at this, but maybe I missed something? I've not got much experience with object-oriented programming, this project is intended to teach myself how to use it properly, so I'd like to learn the 'best way' if possible.
Would this be a good place to use a dictionary?
For example:
classdef UnitLibrary
    properties (Constant)
        Dictionary = dictionary( ...
            "Metre", Unit(quantity = Quantity.Length), ...
            "Inch", Unit(quantity = Quantity.Length, conversionFactor = 0.0254), ...
            ...
    end
end

Would this be a better way of doing it? I would still need to access the Dictionary property of the library object in methods, which leads to the same annoyance as before when the 'fromString' and related methods.
If anyone has ever tried to set up a similar thing, either in MATLAB or in an object-oriented programming languange then please let me know how you did it.
Also just to clarify, I am aware that MATLAB has its own 'unit library' package available. However, this 'library' system will not just be used for units but also many other things. Secondly, I'm doing this as a side project to teach myself something, rather than needing a unit system for something else.

You don't need the fromString  function, you can directly do UnitLibrary.("Metre") and UnitLibrary.Metre interchangeably with the example above. I think this question would be improved if you could [edit] it to include the specific behaviours you want to achieve, i.e. with your above UnitLibrary class and direct access to properties via a string or otherwise, what are you missing which you can't do as-is?
